# XNA 4.0 - Cooldown animation after press a key

Tags: c#, animation, xna

I am working in XNA 4.0 and I got some trouble.
In the beginning I am sorry for my English. 
Yeah and I tryed find over whole WWW and google reasons, codes, answers and more ...

I'll start with what I'm currently doing XNA if I start him (meaning my code/game).
It generate 2 pictures of 2 players and one animation if I don't give it to comments.
Also my players can run over the screen and shoot some bullets, yea its OK.
But if I want use my animation i will delete syntax for comments, animation works, but not after press key to shoot and if I press key to shoot, it will crash my game, I don't know the reasons.

How do I want to make it work:
I want just do now cooldown after press some of key. You will press key and it will start cooldown of abillity (the ability to shoot). Just I don't know how to do it and I need help, because if this won't work, it will be bad with me in school ... :(

I tryed my best translate names of variables to English.
Here is how I tryed it in Player1:[Player1](http://pastebin.com/vVMVT8dw)

Please help, its timed work. If you have questions, ask me, I will try give you answers.

Comment: If you can share project I can try to solve it. Because I don't know how your animation works and what the errors appear within a crash.

Comment: Ok, after school I will share my project, I will try translate my project to english, I think it will be better. Thanks

Comment: So I am back, I tryed to translate my project, I don't know, why my project won't work. So I added to zip, my original work where are variables in Czech and in Czech it works.
Here is link: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6MrddbMlA6HZl9xTU5XMTgtWEU&usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, I will try to solve problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your bullets inherit Sprite class. Your Sprite class has a field - animation. When you started shoot the bullet has been created. But had no animation, thus your update and draw method actually tried to handle an animation which wasn't created. So I made condition if animation != null then handle animation.

```
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        position += speed * direction;
        if (animation != null)
            animation.Update();
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Game1 g = (Game1)Game;
        g.SpriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
        if (animation != null)
            g.SpriteBatch.Draw(animation.GiveTexture(), position2, Color.CornflowerBlue);
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

As also I edited your Animation class and made simple timer System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch to calculate cooldown of a bullet which is firing on key press Key.G. Player classes are edited a little bit as well. Now your cooldown animation starts when you shoot and it doesn't allow you shoot till it ends.

You can download the full edited project [here](https://onedrive.live.com/#cid=59802AFBA7F9048E&id=59802AFBA7F9048E%21112).